# XACML policy - getting "indeterminate" response

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to explore XACML in WSO2. I am using the below policy in WSO2 IS 5.3.0

```
    <Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="InStorePolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
       <Target>
          <AnyOf>
             <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">access</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                </Match>
             </AllOf>
          </AnyOf>
       </Target>
       <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_for_employee">
          <Target>
             <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                   <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Employee</AttributeValue>
                      <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://test.org/claim/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                   </Match>
                </AllOf>
                <AllOf>
                   <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Manager</AttributeValue>
                      <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                   </Match>
                </AllOf>
             </AnyOf>
          </Target>
          <Condition>
             <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/support</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/team</AttributeValue>
                </Apply>
                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
             </Apply>
          </Condition>
       </Rule>
       <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_for_manager">
          <Target>
             <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                   <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Manager</AttributeValue>
                      <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                   </Match>
                </AllOf>
             </AnyOf>
          </Target>
          <Condition>
             <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/business</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">private/leadership</AttributeValue>
                </Apply>
                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
             </Apply>
          </Condition>
       </Rule>
       <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Rule_deny_all"></Rule>
    </Policy>
```

I have created users with Manager and Employee roles. But when I use the 'Tryit', with the following values,  I am getting "Indeterminate"

action : access,
subject : employee1,
resource : /private/team

Also, I am getting  "Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute" error in the server console. I couldn't find more details.

Could anyone help me understand the issue ?

-Albie Morken

Comment: I tried with WSO2 IS 5.4.0 alpha and it works there. 

But I am using a prepackaged WSO2 IS, since I have to use that with WSO2 API Manager, as mentioned below 

[link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager)

Is there a prepackaged version available for 5.4.0 alpha and the corresponding WSO2 APIM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your policies using the Axiomatics Policy Server and I believe I might have found the root cause to your issue. Some of your attributes are marked as `MustBePresent`. This is an optional flag which, if set to true, will make the evaluation return Indeterminate if there is no value for your attribute.

### Access Review

Here are the three different ways access can be granted:

1. `stringAtLeastOneMemberOf(stringBag("private/support" , "private/team") , Attributes.resource.resource_id ) AND "access" == Attributes.action.action_id AND "Employee" == http://test.org/claim/role`
2. `"Manager" == http://wso2.org/claims/role AND stringAtLeastOneMemberOf(stringBag("private/support" , "private/team") , Attributes.resource.resource_id ) AND "access" == Attributes.action.action_id`
3. `"Manager" == http://wso2.org/claims/role AND "access" == Attributes.action.action_id AND stringAtLeastOneMemberOf(stringBag("private" , "private/business" , "private/leadership") , Attributes.resource.resource_id )`

The notation above use [ALFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)), the Abbreviated Language for Authorization.

### Policy Review

This is what your policy looks like in the Policy Editor.

[image: Axiomatics Policy Editor]

There are a couple of odd things in your policy BTW:

1. You use 2 similar yet different attribute identifiers (http://wso2.org/claims/role and http://test.org/claim/role). Is that intentional?
2. None of your policies and rules are described which makes understanding them harder.
3. I'm not sure you need to mark attributes as `MustBePresent`. I typically do not but that's likely a preference.
4. You use conditions when a simple target would do

#### Before

[image: The rule before update]

#### After

The following is easier to read than the former.

[image: The rule with a combined target]

#### Sample Request / Response

The following samples leverage the JSON profile of XACML ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML#The_JSON_Profile_of_XACML) | [Blog post](https://www.axiomatics.com/blog/using-json-and-rest-profiles-for-external-authorization/))

```
{
    "Request": {
        "AccessSubject": {
            "Attribute": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": "http://test.org/claim/role",
                    "Value": "Employee"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Resource": {
            "Attribute": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id",
                    "Value": "private/support"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Action": {
            "Attribute": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id",
                    "Value": "access"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Environment": {
            "Attribute": []
        }
    }
}
```

And the matching response

```
{
  "Response" : {
    "Decision" : "Permit",
    "Status" : {
      "StatusCode" : {
        "Value" : "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok",
        "StatusCode" : {
          "Value" : "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked, after I made MustBePresent 'false'